# sqlite left join syntax with create table as

Tags: sqlite, left-join

I have two large tables in sqlite3 and need to do a left join and create a new table (myTable). I also need to match two columns (different names) from each of the tables and then rename them for the third table (myTable). Below is my current code, but I keep receiving an error at the end: ambiguous column name faa.city

Table 1: airplane

Table 2: faa

First, I'm matching airplane.code with faa.iata and then renaming it to oCity (myTable.oCity). Second, I'm matching airplane.dCode with faa.city and renaming it to dCity (myTable.dCity).

```
CREATE TABLE myTable AS
SELECT airplane.code AS oCity, faa.city AS dCity, airplane.month, airplane.dayOfMonth, airplane.uniqueCode, airplane.fNumber, airplane.scheduledTime
FROM airplane, faa
LEFT JOIN faa
WHERE airplane.code = faa.iata
AND airplane.dCode = faa.city;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need an `on` clause.  Second, you need to use the correct table aliases.  Third, you don't need to mention `faa` twice in the `from` clause:

```
CREATE TABLE myTable AS
    SELECT a.code AS oCity, faa.city AS dCity, a.month, a.dayOfMonth, 
           a.uniqueCode, a.fNumber, a.scheduledTime
    FROM airplane a LEFT JOIN
         faa
         ON a.code = faa.iata AND a.dCode = faa.city;
```

A simple rule:  Never use commas in the `from` clause.